# Solve logical problem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Using any of the rules of inference and Rules of Replacement, prove

$$P \to A\tag{premise} $$

$$ Q \to B \tag{premise}$$

$$(P \land Q) \to (A\land B)\tag{conclusion)}$$

I was able to solve it to the conclusion of $(P\lor Q) \to (A\lor B)$, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the Rules of Replacement and Implication to get to the conclusion in the title.

Comment: Alexander: does the edit above (what you see here as posted) the question you intended to ask.

Comment: Yes, the edit is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start with: $(P \to A) \equiv (\lnot P \lor A)$ by [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)).

The same with: $(Q \to B) \equiv (\lnot Q \lor B)$.

By [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) we get:

> $\lnot P \lor A \vdash \lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor A$

and:

> $\lnot Q \lor B \vdash \lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor B$.

Now we apply [Conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction) to get:

> $(\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor A) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor B)$.

So far we have:

> > $(P \to A),(Q \to B) \vdash (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor A) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor B)$.

The next step is to apply [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) to get:

> $(P \to A),(Q \to B) \vdash (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \lor (A \land B)$.

Then use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Substitution_form):

> $(P \to A),(Q \to B) \vdash \lnot (P \land Q) \lor (A \land B)$

followed by [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) to conclude with:

> > $(P \to A),(Q \to B) \vdash (P \land Q) \to (A \land B)$.

Answer (score 1):

We are given the two premises: $$(1)\; P \to A\tag{premise} $$

$$(2)\; Q \to B \tag{premise}$$

---

And we are to derive:

> $$\therefore \;(P \land Q) \to (A\land B)\tag{conclusion)}$$

---

Proof:

> $(1) \;P \to A \quad \text{premise}$
>
> $(2)\; Q\to B \quad \text{premise}$
>
> $(3) \;\qquad \text{Assume}\;\; P\land Q$
>
> $(4)\qquad\qquad P\qquad \text{ (3), $\land$-elim}$
>
> $(5)\qquad\qquad Q\qquad \text{ (3), $\land$-elim}$
>
> $(6) \qquad \qquad A\qquad\text{ (4), (1), modus ponens}$
>
> $(7) \qquad\qquad B\qquad\text{ (5), (2), modus ponens}$
>
> $(8)\qquad\qquad A\land B\qquad\text{ (6), (7), $\land$-intro}$
>
> $(9)\;\;  (P \land Q) \to (A\land B)\qquad\text{(3)-(8), $\to$-intro}$
> $$ $$

What we have proven is,  given the first two premises, **IF** $P\land Q$, **THEN** $A\land B$, hence, we've proven $(P \land Q)\to (A\land B)$.
$$ $$
Note:  modus ponens is also known as  $\to$-elimination.

And in the proof itself, "elim" is short for "elimination", and "intro" is short for "introduction."